# angular 1.3.6 ng-messages are present regardless of value

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to incorporate some of the new features of 1.3 into our app.  I have a form and couldn't seem to get ng-messages to work.  So I put it in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/x4pKUJHNkxkDhJWxbVAl?p=preview) and I still seem to be doing something wrong.  My view looks like this:

```
<form name="profileForm"
    ng-submit="profile.submit(profileForm.$valid)"
    novalidate>

  <input type="text" name="favoriteNumber" 
       ng-model="profile.number"
       required ng-minlength="5" />
  <div class="errors" ng-messages="profileForm.favoriteNumber.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">this is required</div>
    <div ng-message="minlength">this is too short</div>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Save" />

</form>
```

I expected to see only one ng-message tag at a time, but both are present when the page loads.
At least I expect the message to go away as their validation criteria are met, but no matter what I type in the input, both messages are always present.  It is as if I didn't include the ng-messages script at all.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var app = angular.module("demo", ['ngMessages']);`

include ngMessages module in you application module as a dependency.
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1gBReViAqKXSeG803VaU?p=preview)

Comment: sigh - thanks.  i guess i just needed another pair of eyes haha